# Is it possible Embed flexviewer in wordpress and how?

Tags: plugins

I have a [flex viewer application](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/communities/flex-viewer/) and need to embed it in my WordPress site. I try so many ways to make it happen without luck. I try used a plugin called **swfobj**, by put simple code as follow : `[swfobj src= "index.swf" width ="100%" height ="550"]`, but still get an error notification as follow : *WidgetManager #error2036*..

Is it because wordpress prevent to denied flex viewer application or what?

Comment: Hi, welcome to GIS Stack Exchange :) This reads like a Wordpress and/or html/web-dev question and not about GIS. That said, [check your paths](http://forums.arcgis.com/threads/49219-WidgetManager-Error-2036), which could be not read properly because of permissions or security restrictions (likely IMO).

Comment: eep. I migrated to Wordpess.se when I only intended to *"put on hold, recommend migration".* sorry.